# How to stop sunrise from auto populating events in Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar

There's a new Sunrise entry every day in my Google Calendar. How do I stop it?

Answer (score -1):

Most likely you have already subscribed to a Sunset/Sunrise calendar (willingly or not).

Easy to stop it though if you **uncheck or delete it altogether form the sidebar under `Other calendars`**.

[image]

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: No, I don't have any calendars under "Other calendars" unfortunately.